# Recommender System - Binary Ratings without explicit dislike

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently looking into developing a system in which media from various sources is collected, with the notion that the media collected for each user is media they **'like'**. This results in a set of *n* users, each with their own respective set of *m* liked items.

Most papers on recommender systems I find either require explicit ratings, or work within a binary domain with likes **and dislikes.**

How would I go about making recommendations based mainly on what is in a users preferred / liked set, without information on what they dislike?

Thanks.

Comment: What approaches have you considered?  Have you considered translating each "like" to 1, each "non-like" to 0, and then work with a binary domain, e.g., fill in a $n \times m$ matrix with 1's and 0's and then use standard collaborative filtering methods, e.g., matrix factorization?  Have you considered using k-nearest neighbors classification or some kind of clustering algorithm, with a distance function that takes into account the semantics of "likes" and "non-likes"?

Comment: @D.W. Hey, I'm new to the area of ML and recommender systems but your n x m matrix option was my initial idea. I also looked into k-nearest neighbours which looked viable. I thought I'd ask here just to confirm I was on the right track and get an idea of what people with more experience would recommend as I'm looking to implement two different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification), in which the learner is given only positive examples, but must later on classify new instance into positive and negative. An example is intrusion detection – the learner is given the network in its working state, and tries to identify outlying behavior.